# Why Django does not store relations in a database

Tags: python, django, django-models

An empty Django 3.2 project, and only this content in the model.py file and django admin enabled:

```
from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Tag Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Post Name")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        tags = ['a','b','c','d','e']
        for tag in tags:
            dbtag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
            self.tags.add(dbtag)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        print (self.tags.all())
```

Problem:

The code creates tags and saves it to the database.
The code creates relations, because print -command prints:

<QuerySet [<Tag: a>, <Tag: b>, <Tag: c>, <Tag: d>, <Tag: e>]>

But relations does not store it in the database, Why?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And _where_ do you check for these relations? These relations would be stored in an extra table since this is a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Why two `super().save()` calls, by the way? Wouldn't that save the same object twice, resulting in two copies?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat is right. Code works fine and records are created in extra table.

Comment: @00 No. Only one record is created but it's really not necessarily to call the second `save`

Comment: @00 Although that is unneeded, two objects won't be created as in the second call the object already has a pk so it would be counted as an update. (but yes again, it is redundant)

Comment: @zelenyjan @AbdulAzizBarkat Right, so Django doesn't let de database create a new primary key once it has obtained one (that is attached to the object, e.g. `self.pk` exist)?

Comment: @00 Yes. You can use this if you want a copy of object. Just set `self.pk=None` and call `save` and you will get copy.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat When I check a Post in Django admin after the adding it, it has no tags selected.
Also when I look at the contents of db.sqlite3, then the test1_post_tag table is empty.

Comment: @zelenyjan Are you using Django 3.2 and django admin to creat post? The code creates a Post, It stores the Post in a database. The code creates a, b, c, d, e, Tags, It stores them in a database.
The code creates relations. But it doesn't store them in the database !!! The test1_post_tag table is empty! Also in Django admin when you check the Post, there are no tags selected!

Comment: @Masa yes, Django 3.2 and sqlite3 as database and it works. Maybe try to delete database and run migrations again.

Comment: @zelenyjan I noticed an interesting thing, this code works perfectly when using a shell (python manage.py shell) and storing relations in a database. But when you use Django admin to add Post, it doesn't save relations!

Comment: @Masa ok, that make sense. You send empty `tags` in form in django admin. So you remove tags added in `save` method. If you set `tags` as `readonly_fields` (`readonly_fields = ["tags"]`) in admin it will work.

Comment: @zelenyjan Thank, that works! But what if I need that the tags can be edited in django admin?

Comment: @Masa not sure what's your use case is but it looks you have some fixed tags and want to add all of then by default to the new post. If so I would create all tags outside that `save` method and when adding new post using admin I would select all of them by default.

Comment: @zelenyjan Tags will be generated based on the content of the post, so they are different in each post. And the intention is to move that code into signals.py and run it only on create (if created). And the user could add/remove tags after that.